# NSGridView custom view intrinsic size

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nsgridview

I'm building a simple NSGridView, and want to have a custom NSView as each element of the grid. Eventually, each NSView will be a xib based label (NSTextField) centered in the NSView.
The problem I am having is with the intrinsic size of the NSView. I want to define the size of the NSView and have auto layout work based on that. I added this code to the custom view (labelView):

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    return NSSize(width:100, height:100);
};
```

And it is indeed called; but apparently ignored. As a test, I have on the same row some other labels, and the height for the row is always set to the largest of the row text heights (including the label in the custom view); but the length is set to the longest of column text fields, ignoring the  label in the custom view. And anyway, I want to arbitrarily make the NSView a certain height and length, as I tried (but failed) to do with the intrinsicContentSize.

NSStackview seems to do the right thing; but NSGridView does not.

I can force the width of a particular column with

```
    grid.column(at:0).width = 400;
```

but want I really want to do is define the size of the NSView, and let autolayout use that as a building block.

This strikes me as a conceptual error on my part, so if someone could explain these NSGridView-autolayout-NSView subtleties, I think many might benefit.

Comment: you are fresh to swift.. you dont need the `;`, did you try to `grid.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` ?

Comment: I did, but I may not have been using it correctly. What I have found is that the width is respected in intrinsicContentSize, but not the height; and the label.heightAnchor is respected but not the label.widthAnchor:

Comment: `override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize{
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        return NSSize(width:390,height: 200) // 200 can be anything, no change
    };
mainLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 430.0).isActive = true // does nothing`

Comment: just had a read up again about grid views, maybe leading you in a wrong direction.  Dont you actually define NSGridRow height explicitly and NSGridColumn width explicitly, which defines the Cells size where you UIView is nested in? Or are you trying to stick with the idea that you can have a CollectionView just like on iOS?

Comment: What is `yPlacement` of the grid view?

Comment: I think you can size the grid two ways: top down, as Ol Sen suggests, where you explicitly set the row and column dimensions, or bottom up, where each cell has a possibly different intrinsic size, and auto layout calculates everything. I want to do the latter.
yPlacement = xPlacement= raw value of 2, which I think is NSGridCellPlacementLeading

Comment: yPlacement is the value of NSGridCellPlacement that defines the placement of the view  vertically in the cell.  xPlacement defines the horizontal placement.  It looks like the values can alsridCellPlacementInherit option.  The backing layer CALayer is apparently the same size as the NSGridView display.  What I'm trying to do is identify the origins and sizes of the cells in the backing layer so that I can put different color backgrounds in the cells in a checkerboard pattern.  It doesn't help that the vast majority of the documentation pages are marked "Overview is not available".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, tried to use custom NSView's inside a NSGridView and couldn't get them to draw correctly. What finally worked for me was setting the following:

```
let gridSize = 5
let cellSize: CGFloat = 50

gridView.xPlacement = .fill // this was key part of the solution
gridView.yPlacement = .fill

for i in 0 ..< gridSize {
    gridView.row(at: i).height = cellSize
    gridView.column(at: i).width = cellSize
}
```

Note that I'm setting the size of each cell with the row height and column width of the NSGridView, and not using the NSView size, but this is the only way I got it working.