# How do I set a border or background image for an individual cell in NSGridView?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, nsgridview

I see where I can apply a background image to the entire backing layer of a NSGridView.  However, what I want to do is to apply a NSBox or NSColor to the background of a single NSGridCell object so that I can distinguish where the cell boundaries are.

The contentFrame of the NSGridCell only appears to contain the NSView that is inside the Cell so it doesn't give me the width of the column or the height of the row.  The width and height properties of NSGridRow and NSGridColumn objects are zero when I look at them and somebody said that these properties were for setting the width and height rather than obtaining the values after laying out the various cells.

A related question appears to be [NSGridView custom view intrinsic size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184453/nsgridview-custom-view-intrinsic-size)

Does anyone know how to apply a box or background image for a specific cell?